# Duplicate Title Tags showing up in GWT even after redirect rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, google-search-console

In Google Webmaster Tools we have multiple pages showing duplicate Title Tags.

The majority of these pages just list the old (Joomla) and new (WordPress) urls …

Example:

/page-url-name.htm

/page-url-name/

But we set up a rule in the htaccess file to simply redirect the old ".htm" url to the new "/" url.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which when the old .htm url is entered it simply redirects to the correct page.

Does anyone know why these are showing up at all and if they found a way to fix it?